# How can I make string tighten around a soft object

Tags: collision, soft-body, force-fields

I've used blender for a couple months, my knowledge is limited to basic modelling.
I'm trying to get the effect of string being tied around a soft object. Like this string around my finger. Not sure what to call this effect so I've had a hard time trying to find some sort of tutorial. [image]

At the moment I am trying to use soft body and collisions with a force field to get the string mesh to tighten around my subject. The two torus are my 'string' which have soft body and collision on them. The bird has a soft body. And the force field has a negative strength of 20 to shrink the torus around the bird.
[image]

When I play forward it seems like the bird doesn't correctly detect the torus and the torus just goes through the bird.
[image]

I don't need the string to animate, I was just hoping once the string tightened I could bake the mesh with the desired effect.

If you know a simpler way to get the effect I need without simulations that would be great too.

Answer (score 7):

I just tried out this, and it worked "ok":

I just created a cylinder with soft body and some subdivisions.

I created a torus as rigid body -> animated.

Then i just animated the scale of the torus.

Result:

[image]

[image]

video: https://youtu.be/D0N_39XnB04

and here i tried pretty much the same as above (don't forget the collision modifier for the rigid body) but more in the direction as your finger was:

[image]

I think soft body simulation is doing a pretty good job here. And i didn't even tweak a value. All soft body default settings.

But of course - soft body simulation take really time to calculate/render.

blend file of my last test: [image]

video result: (remember: default settings, so the softbody shakes a bit ;)) https://youtu.be/7zldLlAdN-w

Comment: nice, just cut the gravity to avoid the bouncing

Comment: thank you!!! ;)

Comment: This looks like a great solution, I opened your file but nothing happened. The red spiral just went straight through the cylinder. Do I need to enable something? Soft body has worked for me before, I got a ball to move in some sort of soft body like manner. Or perhaps my laptop can't handle it :(

Comment: @SamanthaA: Yes, you have to calculate the physics. So select the cylinder, press on "physics settings" and then hit "bake". After that you can start the animation. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bchk9.png. Be aware: This can take some time - depends on the hardware capabilities of your computer.

Comment: Ok that worked on your file. So I'm trying to test this solution in a new file with a ball as a soft body then a torus as the collision. It's almost the result I need and I'm reading through the Blender documentation for the different settings and I can't quite get the result I need. As the torus approaches the ball, some vertices of the ball poke outwards like it wants to stick to the torus. Once the torus is a little tight around the ball, some of the ball is still poking through the torus, almost as if the vertices don't want to shrink the distance between each other.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to use sculpting, with the crease brush, but you have to create enough geometry, adding and applying a SubSurf modifier, or multires, or dynamic topology while sculpting (i.e. this cylinder has 10.000 vertices).

[image]