# How can I tighten the straps on the soft body?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, soft-body

I'm a beginner who saw the following on Instagram.
The comment says that they used the geometry node.
There is a tutorial that wraps the strap around the cylinder,
but I can't see it tightening while pressing down on a soft object.
How could I achieve this?

https://www.instagram.com/p/CeHUfOZo6nB/?igshid=MDJmNzVkMjY%3D
[image]

Comment: Look at the answer for [How can I make string tighten around a soft object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228350/111042) that includes an example blend file.  Or are you determined to use geometry nodes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I saw the post you mentioned, and I saw the example file. Even if I set the same value as that, it doesn't work that way in mine.
And it's okay not to use a geometry node, but I think it would be cool if I could.

Comment: Perhaps some clues in https://youtu.be/8KbNJMS9vR4 as far as the wrapping, however still not the SB squeezing.

Comment: On their twitter. But to make it easier and end up looking for it for one hour use this link: https://twitter.com/lateasusual_/status/1470465247668494342 It's in first comment